# Definition of a congruence in Chinese Remainder Theorem

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, arithmetic

I'm learning modular arithmetic right now and having a small hang-up in the application of the definition of a congruence.

The book states that a congruence $c \equiv d$ (mod $n$) can be written if

- $(c - d) = kn$, i.e., $(c - d)$ is divisible by $n$

---

The problem I am having arises during the proof of the Chinese Remainder Theorem. Specifically, the line that states Let $x_{1} = 1 - sa = tb$ then we see that:

- $x_{1} \equiv 1$ (mod $a$)
- $x_{1} \equiv 0$ (mod $b$)

Take the first congruence: Wouldn't it be $x_{1} \equiv -1$ (mod $a$) i.e., $a-1$ (mod $a$)?

- Since the expression $x_{1} = 1 -sa$ can be rewritten as $1 - x_{1} = sa$ and thus we could equate $1 = c$ and $x_{1} = d$ with the definition.

---

Since I've been writing this I reviewed the rules of congruence and noticed the rule:

- $\forall c,d \in \mathbb{Z_{n}}$, $a \equiv b$ (mod $n$) iff $b \equiv a$ (mod $n$)
- Would this rule be the reason why we can say $x_{1} \equiv 1$ (mod $n$)?

Or would it simply just be the case that if something is divisible by $kn$ then it is also divisible by $-kn$? Hence we could just write the congruence in question as $x_{1} - 1 = -kn$ and have that still apply without having to fiddle around with the $c$ and $d$ from the original definition?

Comment: Yes, anything divisible by $r$ is also divisible by $-r$. $x\equiv1\pmod a$ because $x-1=-sa$ is a multiple of $a$.

Comment: Thanks, Gerry, for the verification.

Comment: $\!\bmod\, \color{#c00}a\!:\,\ 1-sa\equiv 1\ $ (proof: $\,\color{#c00}{a\equiv 0}\,\Rightarrow 1-s\,\color{#c00}a\equiv 1-s\,\color{#c00}0\equiv 1\,$ by [Congruence Sum & Product Rules](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/879262/242)) thus $x\,\equiv 1-sa\equiv 1\Rightarrow x\equiv 1\,$ by *transitivity* of congruence (being an equivalence relation).  It is better to quickly master such *equational* congruence arithmetic (vs. divisibility *relational* arithmetic) since it allows us to reuse our well-practiced intuition on arithmetical equations - going back to grade school.

Comment: Otoh, if you keep unwinding congruences into their definition in terms of the divisibility relation then that will obfuscate that innate arithmetical key ideas at the heart of many modular arithmetic applications.

Answer (score 1):

Let $x_1=1−sa=tb$.

Then $x_1-1 = (-s)a$ and so $x_1\equiv 1\mod a$.

Comment: Ok as I had thought thank you for the verification.